# Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Смотрел обучающее видео по библиотеке socket питона с применением TCP  и столкнулся с проблемой. Я запускаю отладчик сервера до момента принятия сообщения, сервер готов к приему. Однако после попытки соединения клиентом, у меня вылезает ошибка:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/*/PycharmProjects/socket/socket_TCP_client.py", line 4, in <module>
    sock.connect(('', 8888))
OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен
```

У автора полностью идентичный код, ошибок не выдает, давность видео 2 года. Я пробовал менять порты и адреса("0.0.0.0", "") и у клиента, и у сервера, однако ошибка во всех случаях одна и та же. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я неправ.

Код сервера:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    try:
        client, addr = sock.accept()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
        break
    else:
        result = client.recv(1024)
        client.close()
        print('Message is', result.decode('utf-8'))
```

Код клиента:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('', 8888))
sock.send(b'funny message')
sock.close()
```

Спасибо

Comment: Не думаю, что в `sock.connect(('', 8888))` будет понятно куда вы хотите подключиться. Указывайте явно адрес, например `sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `connect` адрес должен быть указан, например:

```
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
```

Кст, а вот для `bind` можно и не указывать, так будет работать:

```
sock.bind(('', 8888))
```